# Spring Boot JPA Exception : Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a REST webService App using Spring, displaying data is working fine, however when I want to save the object with a ManytoMany relationship in the Database I am facing an Exception, I've looked for similar questions but no result,  Here is my Code.

Vehicule.class

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="idVehicule")
public class Vehicule implements Serializable {
//Attributes
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idVehicule;

@Column(name = "refVehicule", unique = true)
private String refVehicule;
private double prixEstimatif;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateCreation;
private String typeVehicule;
private String commentaire;
private int isDeleted;


@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "vehicule_portes", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_vehicule") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_porte") })
private List<Porte> listPortes;
}
```

Porte.class

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="idPorte")
public class Porte implements Serializable {


    //Attributes
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPorte;

    @Column(name = "typePorte" , unique = true)
    private String typePorte;
    private String description;
    private int isDeleted;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            mappedBy = "listPortes")    
        private List<Vehicule> vehicule;
}
```

porteController.class :

```
//add a new Porte
@RequestMapping(value="/portes" , method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Porte savePorte(@RequestBody Porte porte){
    return porteRepository.save(porte);
}
```

Here is my stackTrace :

```
2018-11-26 10:53:24.523  WARN 4732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.heuliezbus.entites.Porte]]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.heuliezbus.entites.Vehicule)
2018-11-26 10:53:24.528  WARN 4732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.heuliezbus.entites.Porte]]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.heuliezbus.entites.Vehicule)
2018-11-26 10:53:24.531  WARN 4732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

I am using AdvancedRestClient to test my webService :

[image]

Comment: this error is related to gettters and setters so ensure that getter/setter are proper not double time

Comment: I've already checked them, they are not doubled, and still the same exception.

Comment: Please share your request payload it seems incorrect.

Comment: Here is my payload :
{
  "typePorte": "type porte 3 ",
  "description": "description 3 ",
  "isDeleted": 0
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson failed to deserialization OneToMany objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612148/jackson-failed-to-deserialization-onetomany-objects)

Comment: Can you change your MediaType to MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE . Other point i see in the screenshot that you pass to your isDeleted a string and not a int, means you put the 0 between ""